# How to highlight a single cell in pygtk table?

Tags: python, gtk

Can anyone tell how to highlight a single cell in pygtk table?

Answer (score 1):

Which "table" are you using?

**GtkTable** is a layout container and doesn't really have any selection.

**GtkTreeView** only allows selecting whole rows, although it can place the focus on a particular cell using [gtk.TreeView.set_cursor](http://library.gnome.org/devel/pygtk/unstable/class-gtktreeview.html#method-gtktreeview--set-cursor).

**GtkSheet** is a spreadsheet widget which allows you to actually select a single cell, but it's not officially part of GTK+. I'm guessing [gtk_sheet_set_active_cell](http://vhernandez.github.com/gtksheet/reference/GtkSheet.html#gtk-sheet-set-active-cell) and/or [gtk_sheet_select_range](http://vhernandez.github.com/gtksheet/reference/GtkSheet.html#gtk-sheet-set-active-cell) will do the job.